# how to loop my react data, its not showing my data

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I makes crud with react but i have trouble when try to displaying from data table. please help me
this my code

[my conn to api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm0MZ.png)

this my looping data

[looping code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DdyB.png)

this the console log

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNIJ5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you make an array which contains a lot of arrays. Is this your expectation?

```
rowsData = [
    [{ DocumentID: 1, DocumentName: 2, status: 3, navigation: 4 }],
    [{ DocumentID: 1, DocumentName: 2, status: 3, navigation: 4 }]
]
```